# Kill duplicate Sessions on Server in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-artisan, laravel-5

**What is it about ?**

The database session driver now includes user_id and ip_address so you can easily clear all sessions for a given user.

**What's the Problem**

**[I checked this Article while reading what's new in Laravel 5.2](https://laravel-news.com/2015/11/laravel-5-2-a-look-at-whats-coming/)**

Is there any blog that clearly explains on how to logout the duplicate sessions created using multiple IP address or through the same IP address using multiple browsers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see there is no difficulty with that.

Sample data in this table looks like below:

[image: Session table data]

So you have here `user_id`, browser and last activity timestamp. So if you want you can now add to cron for example running the following query:

```
select user_id, count(*) AS `total` FROM sessions GROUP by user_id HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This will give you users with multiple sessions and you'll be able to decide what to do with them. You can for example remove all sessions for those users or leave only the last one and remove all the others. It's up to you of course.

In the moment when you remove the record from database user will need to login again so for example above if I removed my session for Firefox, I need to login again in Firefox to be logged on my account.

**EDIT**

Be aware that by default there is no `sessions` table (because many users won't use `database` driver for sessions). To create this table you need to run:

```
 php artisan session:table
```

The above command will create sessions migration

and then you need to run

```
 php artisan migrate
```

to apply this migration into database

Comment: @Helper Probably you shouldn't In `users` table it will be `UserID` and here it will be `user_id`

Comment: I assume you set your `.env` file `SESSION_DRIVER=database` (by default it's `SESSION_DRIVER=file`)

Comment: In case I have to delete those record which does not belongs to current logged in user, then how will i recognize this ? I meant, let's say there occurred user_id 2 times then how will I get to know which one I will have to delete. Reason I asked this question because there is probability that somebody try to login with same account through code for web scrapping...so there can be many records for same user.

Comment: As I said, at to cron running the query I showed and then for result set you can do anything you want  - this query will get records for all users (and not for current one because in cron there won't be any logged user)

Comment: Can I avoid creation of duplicate User Session Records in Session Table? Is there any flag that do so in Session Config file?